# How to write test for Laravel update password form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

How to write phpunit test for Laravel update password form?

Here is my test:

```
$user = \factory(\App\User::class)->create(['password' => \Hash::make('password')]);
        $this->actingAs($user);  

        $response = $this->call('PUT', '/user/update-password', array(
            '_token' => csrf_token(),
            'current_password' => 'password',
            'new_password' => 'newone',
            'repeat_new_password' => 'newone',
        ));
        $response->assertStatus(302);        

        $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', ['name' => $user->name, 'password' => \Hash::make('newone')]);
```

And password controller is saving new password like this:

```
....
$user->password = \Hash::make($request->new_password);
$user->save();
....
```

And i get error: *"Failed asserting that a row in the table [users] matches the attributes"*

Update password-form works ok, because i can login with updated password. I guess, that: $this->assertDatabaseHas('users', ['name' => $user->name, 'password' => \Hash::make('newone')]); is making different password, than my password controller.

Any ideas, what is wrong here?

Answer (score 7):

As @Latheeesan suggested `Hash:make()` produces different results...

Therefore use `Hash::check(...` for it, as in this example:

```
$oldPassword = 'password';
$newPassword = 'newone';  

$user = \factory(\App\User::class)->create(['password' => \Hash::make($oldPassword)]);

$this->actingAs($user);  

$response = $this->call('PUT', '/user/update-password', array(
    '_token' => csrf_token(),
    'current_password' => $oldPassword,
    'new_password' => $newPassword,
    'repeat_new_password' => $newPassword,
));
$response->assertStatus(302);        
$this->assertTrue(\Hash::check($newPassword,$user->password));
```

This should make your test fine...

Comment: i don't get it.. It is same code as mine, you just assigned hashed password and then passed its variable to assertDatabaseHas. So there is no difference. When password is updated, laravel is hashing on it's side and these two hashes doesn't match?

Comment: @LinasLg you're right, sorry for that.  I've updated my code example, to make it work...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong here. `Hash::make()` will generate different value, for the same password - this is due to the underlying implementation. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

It's a security measure, it prevents rainbow table attack.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here is right. You can see another easy example:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), User::$password_rules);
    if ($validator->fails()){
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
    }
    $user=Auth::user();
    if(Hash::check($request->get('password'), $user->password)){    
        $user->password=bcrypt($request->get('newpassword'));
        $result=$user->update();
        if($result){
            return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Password updated');
        }
        return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Password could not be updated');
    }
    return Redirect::back()->with('status', 'Current password is wrong');
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks for the "Hash::check" idea. I validated with it, instead of using assertDatabaseHas.